# setUp function for python unittest doesn't use mocks declared over the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

so I'm writing unit tests and I'm having trouble with the setUp function. From what I've seen, it's supposed to just execute code before your function and thus I could put anything that's repetitive in there. However, this function doesn't seem to be applying the mocks I've created as patch decorators over the entire class. This is a small piece of what I want it to look like:

```
@patch('geomet_data_registry.layer.base.get_today_and_now', new=mocked_get_date)  # noqa
@patch('geomet_data_registry.layer.base.load_plugin', new=mocked_load_plugin)
@patch('geomet_data_registry.layer.base.TILEINDEX_PROVIDER_DEF', new=mocked_tileindex)  # noqa
@patch('geomet_data_registry.layer.base.STORE_PROVIDER_DEF', new=mocked_store)
class TestInitBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """ Code that executes before every function. """

        self.maxDiff = None
        self.today_date = \
            datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat().replace('+00:00', 'Z')
        mocked_get_date.return_value = self.today_date
        self.base_layer = BaseLayer({'name': 'model_gem_global'})

    def test_Init(self):
        
        expected_values = {'items': [],...

        base_layer_attr = self.base_layer.__dict__

        self.assertDictEqual(expected_values, base_layer_attr, msg=None)
```

Here I mock the date received so it doesn't mess with my tests, I mock load_plugin, which when used returns a class instance of a certain plugin, I mock TileIndex which is an ES TileIndex and I mock the store, which is a redis store. If I use the code shown above, it doesn't work. When I instantiate the class `BaseLayer` inside `setUp`, none of my mocks are used and I get:

```
-  'receive_datetime': '2021-11-10T12:56:07.371067Z',
?                                              ^^^
+  'receive_datetime': '2021-11-10T12:56:07.371131Z',
?                                              ^^^
-  'store': <MagicMock name='mock()' id='140158154534472'>,
-  'tileindex': <MagicMock name='mock()' id='140158154534472'>,
+  'store': <BaseStore> Redis,
+  'tileindex': <ElasticsearchTileIndex> http://localhost:9200,
```

However, before you tell me maybe my paths are wrong for the mocks or something like that, I can assure you that everything works fine, because the code works if I keep everything the same, except I repeat the class instantiation in every test function. Moreover, it will work if I keep this the same, but I name the `setUp` for example `mySetUp` and call it at the beginning of the function.

Everything works this way and I've already made all my tests without using the `setUp` at all because I remember thinking to myself "this thing is broken I'm not risking using this function in my tests".

Thanks!

Comment: The mocks are not supposed to be applied to `setUp` - they are applied to each individual test.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen So you're telling me I should repeat my class instantiation in every single test function and that's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `mock.patch` decorator is applied to each test function, and during `setUp` the patching has not been done yet.
To use the same mocks for all tests, you have to start/stop mocking in `setUp`/`tearDown` instead. This could look something like:

```py
class TestInitBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.data_patcher = patch('geomet_data_registry.layer.base.get_today_and_now',
            new=mocked_get_date)
        self.data_patcher.start()
        self.plugin_patcher = patch('geomet_data_registry.layer.base.load_plugin',
            new=mocked_load_plugin)
        self.plugin_patcher.start()
        ...

        self.today_date = \
            datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat().replace('+00:00', 'Z')
        mocked_get_date.return_value = self.today_date
        self.base_layer = BaseLayer({'name': 'model_gem_global'})

    def tearDown(self):
        self.data_patcher.stop()
        self.plugin_patcher.stop()
        ...
```

Admittedly this is not as nice as using the decorators. You can still use the decorators for the functions that don't have to already be patched in `setUp`, if there are any.

As a side note: with `pytest` this would be a bit less messy, as you can have the setup and teardown part in the same fixture.

Answer (score 4):

By default the mock.patch decorator is applied to each function in the class starting with `test`. Since `setUp` does not start with `test` it will not be patched by the class decorator by default.

You can change this by setting `patch.TEST_PREFIX` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#test-prefix). If you want it to apply to `setUp` as well you can do

```
patch.TEST_PREFIX = ("test", "setUp",)
```

and use the class decorators as before.